# Does Deleting Comments Impede People from Earning the Pundit Badge?

Tags: discussion, comments, badges

I was skimming through the site's awarded badges and noticed that the [Pundit badge](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/badges/24/pundit) has only been awarded 92 times, which seemed rather low considering the requirements.

Given that mods will do comment clean up fairly regularly, I'm inclined to assume that highly rated comments may be getting deleted thereby preventing others from earning the badge.

Is my assessment on this correct and if so, should we not delete comments that have 5 or more up votes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We do not delete highly rated comments except for cause.

Comment: I can bear witness this, in a very limited fashion: I've sometimes had flags on comments that I thought "obsolete" or "not constructive" declined in the case of comments with even just 3 or 4 upvotes.

Comment: @nitsua60 It's happened, but rare. One (recent) example is a highly-upvoted comment that is just part of a long tangential argument — the argument goes and it stops making sense / being remotely relevant, so it kinda has to go too. (There's the “except for cause” bit.)