# Why has this NLN comment flag been declined?

Tags: support, specific-question, comments, moderation, flagging

[My DM insists on rolling a single save for groups affected by AoE save spells. How does this affect my odds of successfully affecting the enemy?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96749/my-dm-insists-on-rolling-a-single-save-for-groups-affected-by-aoe-save-spells-h/96764#comment225425_96764)

Why has this "no longer needed" flag been declined?

> 2 I think this answer cuts to the heart of the matter quite clearly.
>   Well explained. – stevenjackson121 Mar 20 '17 at 22:43

I am familiar with **the** [comment flagging meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work/17365#17365), including up-vote thresholds, and have read [When should comments be deleted?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2228/when-should-comments-be-deleted/2235#2235)

Comment: Other than not generally follow the reason we often leave stuff, what's your concern about leaving it?

Comment: @NautArch I suspect the asker singled out this comment because it's so obviously no longer needed while other comments—that readers thought *were* still needed—were deleted. That is, perhaps the question's subtext is *If* this *comment is still needed, should the community revisit the criteria for comment deletion?*

Comment: @NautArch I disagree that it's an X/Y problem as this question can be answered purely superficially *without* addressing the subtext. I was more or less trying to avoid a back-and-forth like *Why was this unneeded comment retained?* to which is said *Why do you care?* to which is replied *Because it's not needed* to which is said *Why do you care?* and so on. `:-)`

Comment: @HeyICanChan Fair enough. But if that's the ultimate goal, it seems best to ask that. I mean, I get flags declined and sometimes I don't agree on the response, but I move on. Was trying to figure out why it was important to meta this particular one. If it's the reason you suggest, then that seems like the better question to ask.

Comment: It strikes me as notable that you link in softwareengineering.se's meta about comment deletion rather than any of our many that discuss the same topic. Is there something there you think rpgse users should be seeing that they don't in the native metas?

Comment: My guess is it had upvotes, and the existence of the [Pundit Badge](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/badges/24/pundit) is why it wasn't deleted.

Comment: @williamporter That *would* be an interesting reason! However, if that's the case, it'd be the first time I've seen mods let a comment live just so the user might someday earn a badge! (A user who grouses about a comment like that one being deleted should instead try to earn the Pundit badge by *leaving better comments!*)

Comment: @williamporter [possible](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7000/44723) from my experience (600+ helpful flags - that is site wide the 13th place, I read every flagging and commenting meta -by tag- on rpg.se), however unlikely. 2 up-votes is usually not a notable threshold, it tends to start around 3, unless it is part of a chain that keeps comment logic intact, actual clarification, a joke or information on site policy.

Comment: @williamporter there are also some other fringe cases, those are usually the comment by the question's author that expresses their gratitude without further clarification on why they choose it (probably my most declined flags - outside of poking at locked posts). Then there are comments that make a [trivial observation and express gratitude](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/93646/the-fastest-way-to-remove-bones-from-a-man/93667#comment216291_93667) those tend to be threshold sensitive, but sometimes they are not.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  I am trying to grasp how this issue you have raised is not a case of trying to *pick the fly feces out of the pepper shaker*.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9208/why-has-this-nln-comment-flag-been-declined?noredirect=1#comment29940_9208

Comment: That does not answer my question.  I fail to see a problem at all.  I'll now bow out as we seem to be looking at the same thing through a different lens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, comments expressing appreciation/praise for an answer don't *need* to be cleaned up in the way that the following types of comments do:

- asking clarifying questions (that have been answered)
- suggesting improvements to the answer (and having those suggestions
  either accepted or rejected by the answerer)
- disagreeing with the answerer (and having the answerer continue to
  disagree)
- extended conversations in comments (these usually end up getting
  moved to chat)

As quoted in this question, the comment also had a few upvotes, which generally makes us less likely to remove the comment if there's no immediate, compelling reason to do so.

When flagging comments for cleanup, it's better to focus on the types of comments I've laid out above. Comments praising the answer or a particular part of it may not exactly add much in your view, but they don't really add any significant harm either.

The goal of comment cleanup is generally to get rid of comments that have served their purpose already, or to get rid of extended chains of comments that tend to distract from the answers themselves. In my view, while we *could* delete these sorts of single comments that just praise the answer, it doesn't generally add much benefit to do so - and that's what I hoped to signal by declining the flag.

In any case, the comment in question was flagged again (likely as a result of this meta), so another mod went ahead and deleted it.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and comprehensible answer.

Answer (score 3):

## The guidelines on comment removal aren't black and white

I can't answer why that specific comment flag was declined (only the Mod who declined can do so), but I can say that the 'rules' around comment removal are somewhat fluid.

There isn't a strict line that gets crossed when non-offending comments get removed. I've often flagged comments I thought should go for various reasons and had them decline. And I just move on. It's a comment and it's not that big of a deal.

### If it's not really causing a problem, it's not a problem

Ultimately, comments are ephemeral. While cleaning up is a good thing, it's also not an absolute necessity. Unless the comment is doing a big no-no (being rude/spam), then it's not a huge deal. Even what constitutes an 'answer in comments' can be loose. There have been times where I've flagged for that and had it declined.

It's a loose line. Unless you really think that there's a big problem with a comment, then just let it go if the flag gets declined.

Comment: Thank you for the write-up, but this doesn't answer my question. I feel like you are trying to address a different problem.

Comment: @Akixkisu I can't answer your question directly, but what I was trying to say is there isn't an always-on clear methodology of removing non-problematic comments. And that worrying about them isn't worth your time when a flag is declined (a lesson i learned myself.)

Comment: I do not like it when someone tells me what is worth my time or not. I consider that as condescending and belittingly due to my cultural background, so please don't do that.
I am not asking about flagging guidelines, I have done that at other places and am well aware of the state of the system and its guideline > rules nature. If you feel like my question doesn't make this explicit, then I would appreciate it if you helped me in clarifying my question.

Comment: @Akixkisu I have tried to in the comments to your question, but you did not respond specifically as to what you're trying to ask. Korvin did the same. My goal was not to condescend, but to simply state that there are things out of our control - especially when it's not causing a major problem for the site. You are more than free to spend your time challenging and asking.